# Can't printf contents of a single-linked-list of strings

Tags: c, string, list, function

I have written this piece of code here and I have linked it alright with a couple of other functions and a main and it is working no problem and compiling without warnings (I am using the gcc compiler).

I use an array of pointers (archive.products[]) as an entrance point to multiple lists of strings. I'm still at the beginning so the lists have only one node each.

The problem I've got is that I can't get the function lprintf to show on screen the components of the one-node lists of strings I have created. Note that the printf located inside the push function prints alright. So I know that push is doing it's job...

If anyone has any idea about what might I be doing wrong please drop a reply below.
Thank-you in advance!

```
#define line_length 61
#define max_products 10

struct terminal_list {
  char terminal[line_length];
  struct terminal_list *next;
}*newnode, *browser;
typedef struct terminal_list tlst;

struct hilevel_data {
 char category[line_length];
 tlst *products[max_products];
};
typedef struct hilevel_data hld;

void import_terms(FILE *fp, hld archive){
  char buffer[line_length];
  char filter_t[3] = "}\n";
  int i = 0, j = 0;

  while (!feof(fp)) {    
    fgets(buffer, line_length, fp);
    if (strcmp(buffer, filter_t) == 0) {
      return;
    }

    head_initiator(archive, i);
    push(buffer,archive, i);

    lprintf();

    i++;
  }
}

void head_initiator(hld archive, int i){
  browser = NULL;
  archive.products[i] = NULL;
}

void push(char buffer[],hld archive, int i){
 newnode = (tlst *)malloc(sizeof(tlst));
 strcpy(newnode->terminal, buffer);
//  printf("%s", newnode->terminal);
 archive.products[i] = browser;
 newnode->next = browser;
 browser = newnode;
}

void lprintf(){
  tlst *p;
  p = browser;
  if (p = NULL){
    printf("empty\n");    
  }
  while(p!=NULL){
    printf("%s\n", p->terminal);
    p=p->next;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On : `void lprintf()`

```
if (p = NULL)
```

should be

```
if (p == NULL)
```

Comment: And if you'd written the much clearer `if (!p)` to begin with, there would never have been an issue...

Answer (score 1):

```
if (p = NULL){
    printf("empty\n");    
}
```

I think you mean

```
if (p == NULL){
    printf("empty\n");    
}
```

You're effectively emptying the list with `p = NULL`.